# Um bat que copia um arquivo para uma pasta com o nome dele

Tags: windows, cmd, batch, prompt, bat

Ola, estou tentando criar um bat que copia um arquivo de uma pasta e cria uma pasta com o nome desse arquivo, e joga esse arquivo dentro dela porem nao esta dando muito certo e preciso de ajuda

```
    @echo on
:: Script de cópia do arquivo principal para a pasta no destino, com o mesmo nome do arquivo.

set dir_orig=C:\teste\
set dir_arq=C:\teste\%1

arquivo="BCB _20200115.zip"

:: Verifica se o diretorio não existe
IF NOT EXIST %dir_arq%\ md %dir_arq%

robocopy %dir_orig%\ %dir_arq% %arquivo%

pause
exit /B
```

Answer (score 0):

Veja se é isso que você quer: [Video](https://s6.gifyu.com/images/pasta2-gif.gif)

Aqui está o código:

```
@echo on
:: Script de cópia do arquivo principal para a pasta no destino, com o mesmo nome do arquivo.


set dir_orig=C:\teste\
set dir_arq=C:\teste\BCB _20200115\
arquivo=BCB _20200115.zip

:: Verifica se o diretorio não existe
IF NOT EXIST "%dir_arq%\" md "%dir_arq%"

robocopy "%dir_orig%\" "%dir_arq%\%arquivo%"

pause
exit /B
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off 

cd /d "%~dp1"

set "dir_orig=C:\teste\" & set "dir_arq=C:\teste\%~n1"

:: arquivo="BCB _20200115.zip"

:: Verifica se o diretorio não existe
IF NOT EXIST %dir_arq%\ md %dir_arq%
2>nul mkdir "%dir_arq%"

robocopy "%dir_orig%" "%dir_arq%" "%~nx1"

pause & goto=:EOF
```

**1.** Entre no drive/pasta/ onde está o seu arquivo usando o expansão do seu argumento: `cd /d "%~dp1"`

**2.** Você já tem o **n**ome do arquivo no seu argumento pela expansão `%~n`: `%~n1`

**3.** Não precisa testar se o diretório existe, mande criar já omitindo possível erro: `2>nul mkdir ...`

**4.** não use `exit /...` use `goto=:EOF` (Go To End Of File)